# Background image not showing in Java Game

Tags: java

This is a follow up question to an earlier one of mine. I am making a java game, and it is basically a JFrame with a character image, some healthbars consisting of fillRect()s which are all on top of a background image. The problem is the healthbars and character are appearing but the background image isn't.

Here is a shortened version of the Game class which has the main() and render() methods:

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    public static boolean running = false;
    public Thread gameThread;

    private BufferedImage playerSpriteSheet;
    private ImageManager im;

    private static Player player;
    private static HealthBar healthBars;
    private static BackgroundImage backgroundImage;

    public void init(){
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        playerSpriteSheet = loader.load("/spriteSheet.png");
        SpriteSheet pss = new SpriteSheet(playerSpriteSheet);

        im = new ImageManager(pss);

        backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage("/background.png");
        player = new Player(800, 250, im);
        healthBars = new HealthBar(200, 200);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if(running)return;
        running = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if(!running)return;
        running = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1_000_000_000/amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long now = System.nanoTime();

        while(running)
        {
            delta += (now - lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void tick() {
        player.tick();
    }

    public void render() {

        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3); //Use 5 at most
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //RENDER HERE
        backgroundImage.render(g);
        player.render(g);
        healthBars.render(g);


        //END RENDER
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JLabel backgroundImage;
        JLabel controlKeyPanel;
        JLabel statusLabel;

        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        backgroundImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/background.png"));

        String htmlButtonGuide = "words";
        controlKeyPanel = new JLabel(htmlButtonGuide);

        statusLabel = new JLabel("label");


        frame.add(backgroundImage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(controlKeyPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
        //Program seems to continue running after ESC
    }

    public static Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

}
```

Here is the BackGroundImage class:

```
public class BackgroundImage {

    private Image background = null;


    public BackgroundImage(String s) {
        if(s == null)
        {
            background = getImage(s);
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1200, 600, null);
    }

    public Image getImage(String path) {

        Image tempImage = null;

        File image2 = new File(path);
        try {
            tempImage = ImageIO.read(image2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tempImage;
    }
}
```

I am concerned with the render() method reusing the "g" Graphics object for adding all 3 things to the screen. I was told to not combine lightweight Swing health bars with the heavy AWT background and character? Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the background to show? Should the render method not take care of the background? I only need the background to be put up once. It doesn't need to be constantly updated like the health bars and characters right?

Comment: Are you sure that the image is located at path: `/background.png` ? try to provide a full path!

Comment: You should be rendering everything you want painted directly to the buffer strategy.  So long as you don't add `Canvas` to any other container or any other Swing components to it you won't have issues...You will need to devise some means of keeping the two in sync though ;)

Comment: I tried a full path name and it didn't work. It is stored in the same path as the character image, I used "/characterImage.png" for the character, and it worked.

Comment: MadProgrammer, when you say "painted" are you referring to everything that appears on the screen? (As of now all I have is the health bar, background, and character). And how do you render "to" the buffer strategy?

Comment: Yes.  But you've set your main window up so that here is separation between the canvas and the Swing components (they reside within the same container, but not within each other), so that should be fine...

Comment: `/background.png`, becomes `File("/background.png")`...can you see a problem here.  Are the images stored within the application or are they separate, located on the file system somewhere?

Comment: The images are stored in a folder called "res" in the main project folder.  And I don't think the path name would become a problem when creating a new File object.

Comment: Nice! When I wrote it's the path you insisted it's not the problem... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with...

```
backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage("/background.png");
```

Which becomes...

```
File image2 = new File(path);
```

or

```
File image2 = new File("/background.png");
```

so you can see it...can you see a problem with this?  This is requesting a file which resides at the root location of the current drive...not really what I think you want...

> The images are stored in a folder called "res" in the main project folder

Which would suggest you want to use...

```
backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage("res/background.png");
```

Assuming that the images are not embedded resources....

Next...

```
public BackgroundImage(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        background = getImage(s);
    }
}
```

So, you only ever want to try a load the image when it's reference is `null`???

**Side notes...**

`frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);` is a bad idea, as frames have borders which occupy space within side the frame itself.

Better to override the `getPreferredSize` method of `Canvas` and provide a default size value you want to use and then call `pack` on the frame instead.  This will calculate the size of the frame as the preferred size of it's content PLUS the frame border requirements...

You "game loop" is running wild...

```
while (running) {
    delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
    lastTime = now;
    if (delta >= 1) {
        tick();
        delta--;
    }
    render();
}
```

Basically, this will run as fast as it possibly can and will reduce the opportunity for other threads to run, eventually bringing your game (and probably your PC) to it's knees

This is "simple" concept of a run loop...

```
public void run() {
    init();
    final long amountOfTicks = 60;
    long ns = Math.round(1_000_000_000 / (double)amountOfTicks);

    int frames = 0;
    long frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (running) {
        long startedAt = System.nanoTime();
        tick();
        render();
        long completedAt = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = completedAt - startedAt;

        long frameEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (frameEnd - frameStart >= 1000) {
            System.out.println(frames);
            frames = 0;
            frameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            frames++;
        }

        long rest = ns - duration;
        if (rest > 0) {
            rest = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(rest, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(rest);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

Basically, it tries to ensure that there is enough delay between each iteration in order to maintain the 60fps you are trying to target...without starving the system...

Comment: You are right, there is no harm in adding the "res/" in front of the file name.

Wow, good catch on the "if(s = null)" . My code underwent a bunch of changes, and was just left over.

It works now. THANKS SO MUCH. Been at this ALL day. You rule.

Comment: I will polish up the frame size and game loop later today. Missed those notes in my excitement at Fixing the problem.